# outlook add-in open browser (edge) instead of outlook windows application

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing one web add-in for outlook from Visual studio

when run (debug) the outlook add-in...its open edge instead of the native Outlook Application (office 365 outlook client)

¿any trick?

Thank you

Comment: This sounds like a tooling issue. Have you tried the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you need to open the `Solution Explorer` window and select the web add-in project with a manifest file:

[image: outlook web add-in project in visual studio]

Then you need to open the `Properties` window and change the `Start Action` property choosing the right host application:

[image: changing start action for the outlook web add-in]